# Subgroup of free profinite group is free profinite?

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

The question is already in the title.
It is known that any subgroup of a free group is free. My question is:

**Is a closed subgroup of a free profinite group is again a free profinite group ?**

Comment: Closed subgroups of free profinite groups are exactly the projective profinite groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The free profinite group $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ on one generator is the direct product of the groups $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $p$ prime.
Therefore each $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a closed subgroup of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, but is not free as a profinite group.